# XML removing lines between two tags

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, notepad++, textpad

Need your help. I used to work with reprocessing failed XML a lot in MQ. Sometimes due to some issue lots of message used to move to error queue. Here i need to reprocess the message after resolving the issue. In error queue will have data,but will error tags. message in error queue is not a proper xml. for example condiser a messgae like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Student>
+++++++++++++++++++++some content++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++some content++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++some content++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++some content++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++some content++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
</Student>
```

Error queue message will have above message plus below error details

```
<ErrorMessage>
++++++++++++++++++++++reason for failure will be updated below these tag with will 
many lines    
</ErrorMessage>
```

I can download the whole message in a error queue to next format. I want to remove the data between `<ErrorMessage>` and `</ErrorMessage>` tags. need help for this. will it be easy to do it with the help of textpad or notepad++

i dont have much idea abour regex experssion in notepad++. please help me on this

Comment: It would help if you could, instead of the snippets you posted, post: 1. what you have, 2. what you want

Comment: i have a xml like below    `   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Student 
   +++++++++++++++++++++some content++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    </Student>`
<ErrorMessage>
        ++++++++++++++++++++++reason for failure will be updated below these tag with will 
  </ErrorMessage>
i want like below                                                      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Student 
   +++++++++++++++++++++some content++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    </Student>`

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, You can replace it empty string.

1. Ctlr+H to open Replace dialog
2. Choose Search Mode: Regular Expression
3. Find what: `<ErrorMessage>.*</ErrorMessage>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is to convert

```
<ErrorMessage>
++++++++++++++++++++++reason for failure will be updated below these tag with will 
many lines    
</ErrorMessage>
```

to

```
<ErrorMessage> 
</ErrorMessage>
```

**Solution:**

1) Hit Ctrl+H
2) In **Find What** input box , provide **`<ErrorMessage>(.\*?)</ErrorMessage>`**
3) In **Replace With** input box , provide **`<ErrorMessage>\r\n</ErrorMessage>`**
4) Do not forget to check **". matches newline"**
5) Hit **Replace** / **Replace All**

[image: Search / Replace Snapshot]

**Note:** I've tested this in Notepad++ (6.6.3)